# How to compute for standard deviation in this problem?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

The local administration installed 3500 Incandescent bulbs as part of a new lighting system project. According to them, the bulbs are produced by several companies and have a burn time of 1060 hours on average. The distribution of the burning lives is close to normal. They discovered that the 350th light bulb had burned out after 822 hours of observation. What is the standard deviation of the burning lives of this set of lightbulbs?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! In general, questions are best received when they include important context, like where the problem is from, what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is the 350th bulb the 350th short-lived bulb? if so you can use z-scores. please follow up with your attempt!